# Abrir un Documento de excel usando VS 2019 c#

Tags: c#

es la primera vez que publico algo aqui, espero estar haciendolo de manera correcta para ver si alguien me puede ayudar.
Estoy usando XLWorbook para crear un documento en Excel, con lo cual no tengo problema alguno el detalle es que no encuentro algún método para **abrir** ese mismo documento creado, supongamos que existiera un metodo y fuera "metodo.Open(@"X:\ruta\ruta\Documents\");

Comment: Revisa esto: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1248782/How-to-open-excel-file-using-Csharp-windows-applic

Comment: También puedes buscar en el sitio. Hay algunas preguntas como la tuya.